# How to group jar dependencies in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies

In eclipse, how do I group jars dependencies in one library? It is pretty annoying having the list of dependencies with no grouping option. The project was imported as a maven project.

The jars are the same i have in maven dependencies. I can delete them in "Configure Build Path" but when i download and install maven dependencies, they appeared again.

I am currently using:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).
Build id: 20160218-0600

OS: fedora 23.

[image]

Comment: See that folder for "Maven Dependencies"? The jars should all be under there rather than listed at the top level. It appears either that m2eclipse is misconfigured or that you didn't import your project as a Maven project cleanly.

Comment: I import as maven project, the problem is i have depencencies there and spread like the screenshot shows.